# Error de sintaxis en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un buscador interno, pero al declarar una variable, no la detecta y arroja este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'SE' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
>   in C:\wamp64\www\ProyectoBitacoras\buscador.php on line 27

La línea 27 del código es la siguiente:

```
$conexion = mysql_connect(HOST_DB, USER_DB, PASS_DB) or die (‘NO SE HA PODIDO CONECTAR AL MOTOR DE LA BASE DE DATOS’);
```

Comment: Puedes cambiar los apostrofes por comillas simples ara revisar si este es el error: `'`

Comment: Puedes poner la línea 26 y 27 por favor para evaluar si es en la 26 y de que viene el error, quizás sea un cierre de paréntesis lo que te haga falta.

Comment: Adicional, mysql_connect es una instrucción obsoleta en php 5.5 y eliminada de PHP 7. Actualiza tu código a mysqli_*

Answer (score 3):

El lenguaje PHP posee cuatro formas de identificar las cadenas:

- entrecomillado simple

  ```
  die ('NO SE HA PODIDO CONECTAR AL MOTOR DE LA BASE DE DATOS');
  ```
- entrecomillado doble

  ```
  die ("NO SE HA PODIDO CONECTAR AL MOTOR DE LA BASE DE DATOS");
  ```
- sintaxis heredoc

  ```
   die(<<<EOD
   NO SE HA PODIDO CONECTAR AL MOTOR DE LA BASE DE DATOS
   EOD
   );
  ```
- sintaxis nowdoc (desde PHP 5.3.0)

  ```
  die(<<<'EOT'
  NO SE HA PODIDO CONECTAR AL MOTOR DE LA BASE DE DATOS 
  EOT
  );
  ```

En tu caso no estás usando ninguno de ellos, sino que estás delimitando la cadena por `‘` y por `’`, lo cual no es válido en PHP. Ten en cuenta que PHP es un lenguaje de programación con sus reglas, no es un editor de texto.

Revisar el apartado [***Cadenas de caracteres (Strings)***](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) en el Manual de PHP.